# Choropleth with folium

Tags: python, choropleth, folium

I'm trying to create a choropleth map using folium. I'm using the following site as a guide, although I want to create a world map.

https://python-graph-gallery.com/292-choropleth-map-with-folium/

I got the JSON file from here:

https://github.com/python-visualization/folium/blob/master/examples/data/world-countries.json

My 'test4' data is this:

```
    Country_0                   Count_0
0   United States of America    18425
1   United Kingdom              3070
2   France                      2705
3   Canada                      1498
4   Japan                       1493
5   Italy                       1471
6   Germany                     1418
7   Russia                      800
8   India                       783
9   Spain                       601
10  Australia                   506
11  Hong Kong                   468
12  South Korea                 457
13  Sweden                      396
14  Finland                     324
15  China                       300
16  Belgium                     299
17  Denmark                     297
18  Brazil                      262
19  Poland                      245
20  Mexico                      236
21  Netherlands                 226
22  Argentina                   211
23  Czech Republic              163
24  Austria                     151
25  Ireland                     135
26  Turkey                      134
27  Greece                      131
28  Norway                      124
29  Hungary                     119
30  Switzerland                 99
```

My code is here:

```
import folium
country_count = pd.read_csv('test4.csv')

country_geo = os.path.join('world-countries.json')

m = folium.Map(location=[0, 0], zoom_start=2)
m.choropleth(
 geo_data=country_geo,
 name='choropleth',
 data=country_count,
 columns=['Country_0', 'Count_0'],
 key_on='feature.id',
 fill_color='YlGn',
 fill_opacity=0.7,
 line_opacity=0.2,
 legend_name='Test'
)
folium.LayerControl().add_to(m)
```

I get the following error:

```
JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 7 column 1 (char 6)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it's the json file. I'm assuming you just right clicked and did 'Save link as...' from https://github.com/python-visualization/folium/tree/master/examples/data

go back to https://github.com/python-visualization/folium/blob/master/examples/data/world-countries.json

click the `Raw` tab and then when that comes up you can right click then 'Save as..'

I will also note, you will need change your code a bit. if you look at the json file, you'll see the Countries are stored:

[image]

which is different than the example they give with the us states json which have the states under Features and id.

so notice here it's Feature, properties, name that gives the country value. so, adjust that for the `key_on` attribute:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import folium

country_count = pd.read_csv('test4.csv')

country_geo = os.path.join('world-countries.json')

m = folium.Map(location=[0, 0], zoom_start=2)
m.choropleth(
 geo_data=country_geo,
 name='choropleth',
 data=country_count,
 columns=['Country_0', 'Count_0'],
 key_on='feature.properties.name',
 fill_color='YlGn',
 fill_opacity=0.7,
 line_opacity=0.2,
 legend_name='Test'
)
folium.LayerControl().add_to(m)

m.save('#292_folium_chloropleth_country.html')
```